# spark-submit command not found when submitted using Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have an use-case where i need to do spark submit the python code from Java application. I wrote following code for the same:

```
    String command = "spark-submit /home/hadoop/sample.py "
            + "--input_dir " + getTmpModelInputPath() + "/* " + "--output_dir " + getTmpModelOutputPath();

    final String[] arr = { "/bin/sh", "-c", command};

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arr);

    try {
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("job failed");
    }
```

The command failed with "spark-sumit" not found. When i run the command string directly on master node it works fine. Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Why the "/*" when building your string, as in ...`getTmpModelInputPath() + "/* "+ "--output_dir`...?

Comment: What kind of scenario do you need to call pyspark from java ?

Comment: We are using numpy library and other model code is in python. We have existing code in spark written in Java. Hence, in the flow I want to call python job. Currently, I have different steps I.e add step for java job, then add python job and then again java job. I was looking if I can make it in single job.

Comment: /* is added as input is KMS encrypted and has sub folders. Hence, to read the files we need to add that in end of the path. But, i don’t think it related to the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to root cause the issue for the command not found error. The spark-submit for the main application was started in cluster mode. Hence, the spark-submit done in java code was executed on "Executor Node" and not on master node. The executor nodes doesn't have spark-submit available on the host.

The same above code will work if we submit the main application in client mode. This will ensure that the next spark-submit goes on master node which has spark-submit binary installed in EMR.